# How to define an assignment operator outside my header file in C++?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

I have a header file which contains a class with an assignment operator. Now I want to define my function inside my .cpp file.

My header file contains: `Car &operator=(const Car &other);`
Now in my cpp file I would like to do something like: `Car::Car &operator=(const Car &other)
{
}`

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the right syntax. So how can I define my assignment operator when I have the function declaration and the function definition separated?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're almost there; you need to qualify the function name to indicate that it's a member:

```
Car &Car::operator=(const Car &other) { }
     ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, but why don´t I have to do that when defining my Copy constructor? For example: `Car::Car(const Car&other) {}`

Comment: @phpheini: You are doing that: the `Car::` indicates that it's a member of `Car`, just as it does in the assignment operator. There's just no return type in the constructor definition, since constructors don't return anything.

Comment: Allright, the assignment operator returns my Car object, but why is there a "&" infront of the second Car? Is it a reference?

Comment: @phpheini: Yes, it's conventional to return a reference to the object (i.e. `return *this;`), in order to support chains of assignment (`car1 = car2 = car3;`). You could just return `void` if you want, but that might surprise some people. Some people would space it differently (`Car& Car::...`), to make it clearer that it's part of the type specification.

Answer (score 4):

I write my operators as follows

```
in.h
Car& operator=(const Car &other);
in cpp
Car& Car::operator=(const Car &other) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax is

```
Car& Car::operator=(const Car& other) { }
```

since `operator=()` with its appropriate arguments is the member function.

Answer (score 2):

```
Car& Car::operator=(const Car &other) { }
```

is the way to go.